# vnc cannot connect to host after changing server hostname, server is ubuntu14.04.4

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vnc, hostname

I was using vnc to connect to my new Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS machine.
This afternoon, I changed the host name (first changed `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` file and ran `service hostname restart`). After this, I cound't open a terminal, so I tried doing '`sudo hostname newname`' hoping it to fix something wrong(with the same newname). But it was the same, I couldn't start the term.
I rebooted the server and tried connecting to it using vnc. But I get 
unable to connect to host: Connection refused (10061)
which could be wrong? I regret changing the hostname..

ADD : 
I fond that I have to run
vncserver :1 -geometry 2460x1500
after I login.
When OS says :1 is already running, try
vncserver -kill :1
you may have to remove /tmp/.X1-lock or /tmp/.X11-unix/X1 file.
Now my question becomes, why should I manually start the vnc destop as above when it was automatically launched before my hostname change? I setup an account after the hostname change (as a test trying to solve this problem) and the vnc desktop process Xvnc4 is running automatically for that test account. So something went weird for those accounts that was using vncserver before hostname change. Somebody please help..

Comment: There's no reason to regret the change. -- How are you connecting to the server? Which DNS resolver is running on the machine where you try to launch VNC? How many LAN segments are involved? Which DNS servers are running? Etc...

Comment: I can connect to the server using ssh. I tried connecting to it using 129.abc.32.208:1 as I have been doing. Strange thing is, I can connect to the server using vnc 129.abc.32.208:6 .   (abc is a number)

Comment: I was really asking which command line you use, but anyway. If you connect to 129.abc.32.208:1 and get "connection refused", why don't you analyse the logfiles? Are you sure you connected to display 1? I thought 0 was the default.

Comment: @ClassStacker, the vnc window wants me to type the address not any command. like http://www.pendrivelinux.com/wp-content/uploads/vnc_viewer1.png. The actual address was 129.254.32.208:1. Here 1 means my login is using port 5901. when I use :6, it means port 5906 is being used. I'm not using any firewall in the server. Any clue?

Comment: I repeat, analyse the logfiles.

Comment: where is the log? my login id is ckim. you mean ~ckim/.vnc/z840-HP-Z840-Workstation:1.log ? (BTW z840-HP-Z840-Workstation was the original hostname.)

Comment: I tried 'vncserver' and I could run the second vncdestop for ckim and I could connect to my account using vnc. This is diplay :2 which had default small window. I tried to do 'vncserver -kill :1'  and it said Can't find file /home/ckim/.vnc/abnc:1.pid
You'll have to kill the Xvnc4 process manually  . I tried 'ps -aux | grep vnc' and I could only see vncdesktop for a test account that I made for test (I can connect to that account using vnc). so I guess there is some garbage preventing me from connection which is using old hostname though the original vnc desktop process for ckim :1 is dead.

Comment: hope someone eligible see this. when I do 'sudo service vncserver start' I only see the last vnc desktop of /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf. I guess I should see all the servers. Am I not correct?

Comment: to run 'vncserver :1' you have to remove some files like /tmp/.X1-lock and /tmp/.X11-unix/X1.  After that, you can restart the vncserver.

Comment: I modified my question. see ADD above in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't simply search the VNC config files for the old hostname? And if you don't find it there, you could still search the file system for files having the old hostname as part of their names?

Comment: VNC config files have not been changed. I tried removing files with old hostnames under everyone's .vnc/ but to no avail. This is not a simple problem.